# How to correctly read and increment dates in c++ using localtime and mktime?

Tags: c++, time

I am struggling to execute a simple task. I want to take a date parameter from the command line argument and increment it several times by 1 day. The basic program should:

- read the command line argument as the starting date, and
- loop several times, incrementing that date by 1 day every time.

I convert the `char*` command line argument to a `struct tm`, then convert the `struct tm` to a `time_t` and add 60 * 60 * 24 = 1 day to it. I convert it back to `struct tm` to print it.

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include "time.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char* start_date;
    tm tm_start_date = {}; // solution: needs initialization

    start_date  = argv[1];
    strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d", &tm_start_date);  // YYYY-MM-DD

    char ch_stmt_date[11] = "";
    time_t t_stmt_date = 0;
    tm tm_stmt_date = {}; // solution: needs initialization;

    tm_stmt_date = tm_start_date;

    // time_t -> tm localtime_r(time_t, tm)
    // tm -> time_t mktime(tm) returns time_t

    std::cout << "start_date: " << start_date << " / tm_start_date: " << std::to_string(1900 + tm_start_date.tm_year) + std::to_string(tm_start_date.tm_mon + 1) + 
                    std::to_string(tm_start_date.tm_mday) << std::endl;

    // increment by 1 day per iteration
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)    
    {   
        // tm -> t_time 
        t_stmt_date = mktime(&tm_stmt_date);
        std::cout << "t_stmt_date: " << t_stmt_date << std::endl;
        // + 1 day
        t_stmt_date += 60*60*24;
        std::cout << "t_stmt_date: " << t_stmt_date << std::endl;
        // time_t -> tm
        localtime_r(&t_stmt_date, &tm_stmt_date);
        strftime (ch_stmt_date, 11, "%Y-%m-%d", &tm_stmt_date);
        std::cout << "ch_stmt_date: " << ch_stmt_date << std::endl;
    }
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The start date is correctly read and parsed into the `struct tm`.

However, subsequently I get one of two behaviors of the program:

1. Either I get a -1 on the first call of `t_stmt_date = mktime(&tm_stmt_date);` and a value of `t_stmt_date: 86399` (1970-01-02) in the output. The rest of the loop then works correctly and iterates 5 times, incrementing 1970-01-02 by 1 day.
2. Or, the same code using the same command line parameter parses a nonsensical value on the first call of `t_stmt_date = mktime(&tm_stmt_date);` in the loop which is not a valid date, which, however is also correctly incremented by `60*60*24` on each of the 5 loops.

At this point I am desperate to understand the issue. I am working on Ubuntu 20.04 using gcc.

Thanks for your help.

Edit: Initializing the `struct tm` did the trick!

Comment: `mktime` returns -1 if the data you give it can't be converted.  You should (a) zero out the `tm_start_date` struct before handing it to `strptime` and (b) check `strptime`'s return value for errors.

Comment: Also, instead of adding 86400 to `t_stmt_date`, you could just keep adding 1 to `tm_stmt_date.tm_mday`.  `mktime` has the additional property that it "normalizes" improper dates.  So it will convert January 32 to February 1 for you.

Comment: @SteveSummit: thanks, that did the trick. I wonder though why the uninitialized ```struct tm``` make the code behave this way. Afterall, even if they have "wrong"/uninitialized values, the functions that populate their fields should not care what the current value is. Maybe though that depends on the implementation of ```maketime``` and ```localtime_r```.

Comment: `strptime` isn't perfectly standard, so I don't know about your version, but mine says "If the format string does not contain enough conversion specifications to completely specify the resulting `struct tm`, the unspecified members of `timeptr` are left untouched."  So you'd end up with garbage values in many fields, which might make the date unrepresentable by `mktime`.

Comment: (1) Not sure why you would need to initialise tm_stmt_date. You are assigning it at the very next line. (2) strptime returns a value, I wonder what it would be useful for.

Answer (score 1):

**[NOTE]**

You explicitly mention **"using localtime and mktime"** in the question's title, but I wasn't sure though after reading the rest of the text if that was mandatory, or you just needed to get a task done.

If you cannot use other libraries, just let me know and **I'll remove this answer.**

---

You could use `std::chrono` and Howard Hinnant's [date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) (C++11 onwards, header-only).
Or, should you be able to use a C++20 compiler, you would only need `std::chrono`.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/fMjjPvGYE)

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <sstream>  // istringstream
#include <string>

#include "date/date.h"

int main()
{
    namespace ch = std::chrono;
    namespace dt = date;

    const std::string start_date{"2022-01-31"};  // date
    std::istringstream iss{ start_date };  // to string stream
    dt::sys_days start_day{};  // to a time point with a day duration
    dt::from_stream(iss, "%Y-%m-%d", start_day);
    
    for (auto day{start_day}, end_day{start_day + dt::days{3}};
         day < end_day;
         day += dt::days{1})  // with which we can do date arithmetic
    {
        std::cout << dt::format("%Y-%m-%d\n", day);
    }
}

// Outputs:
//
//    2022-01-31
//    2022-02-01
//    2022-02-02
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution, which I am sure is equally good. In my particular case, I wanted to understand why my solution didn't work using the functions of time.h. You can keep the answer posted for others though.